# How to perform function multiple times with Button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

Hi I have written some code in which a user adds in items and the prices they bought and sold for, then it automatically adds this to an Excel sheet. However, I am having trouble thinking of a way to insert multiple rows of the same item if the quantity sold is >1 without the user entering in the same fields x amount of times. Thanks

I am using Tkinter where a Button executes the Add_Data function.

```
def Add_Data(Event=None):
    workbook = load_workbook('Accounting Sheet.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.active
    sheet.insert_rows(idx=2)
    sheet['A2'] = str(Date_Entry.get())
    sheet['B2'] = str(Shoe_Name_Entry.get())
    sheet['C2'] = str(Purchase_Price_Entry.get())
    sheet['D2'] = str(Sale_Price_Entry.get())
    RRP_Float = float(Purchase_Price_Entry.get())
    Sale_Float = float(Sale_Price_Entry.get())
    sheet['E1'] = str(Sale_Float-RRP_Float)
    Shoe_Name_Entry.delete(0, 30)
    Purchase_Price_Entry.delete(0, 6)
    Sale_Price_Entry.delete(0, 6)
    workbook.save('Accounting Sheet.xlsx')
```

Comment: Why not just have a quantity input which defaults to 1 Then loop 'quantity' times when adding to the excel spreadsheet..

Comment: Hi can you show me what you mean by altering my code please? Not sure entirely what you mean sorry @moken

Comment: if you have to do something many times then use `for`-loop inside function

Answer (score 1):

Include a textbox for 'Quantity' on the input form (which defaults to 1) and obtain that value prior to writing the values to excel. When writing the values to excel include a loop that will iterate 'quantity' times like below.
If the user has Quantity 1 then one entry is made as before. If the Quantity is 2 or more then then after the first row is added to excel it will loop and add another entry with exact same values a 2nd time and so on till the Quantity value is reached.

```
def Add_Data(Event=None):
    workbook = load_workbook('Accounting Sheet.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.active
    quantity = int('0'+Quantity_Entry.get())

    for sale in range(quantity):
        sheet.insert_rows(idx=2)
        sheet['A2'] = str(Date_Entry.get())
        sheet['B2'] = str(Shoe_Name_Entry.get())
        sheet['C2'] = str(Purchase_Price_Entry.get())
        sheet['D2'] = str(Sale_Price_Entry.get())
        RRP_Float = float(Purchase_Price_Entry.get())
        Sale_Float = float(Sale_Price_Entry.get())
        sheet['E1'] = str(Sale_Float-RRP_Float)

    Shoe_Name_Entry.delete(0, 30)
    Purchase_Price_Entry.delete(0, 6)
    Sale_Price_Entry.delete(0, 6)
    workbook.save('Accounting Sheet.xlsx')
```